# How to use Reddit JSON API for search post between dates?

Tags: python, reddit

Reddit provides API like this (https://www.reddit.com/r/python/top.json?limit=100). I want to fetch posts between dates. How do I do it?

I am using Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PRAW` and pass in a UNIX timestamp for a start_time and end_time. This is how you would do it for a subreddit:

`for submission in subreddit.submissions(start_time, end_time):
                print(submission)`

This is done through the `submissions` function and documentation for that is [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submissions).